# Class module-info is missing a super type

Tags: android, gradle

I am trying to build an android application with some dependencies however one of them is causing this error:

```
Illegal class file: Class module-info is missing a super type.
```

The dependency causing the issue is [JOML](https://github.com/JOML-CI/JOML) a math library for use with OpenGL.

The dependency is included as

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: '*.jar', dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'org.joml:joml:1.9.9'
    ...
}
```

I am using android studio/gradle version 3.1 and build tools version 27.0.3.

I have tried clean and rebuild and clearing Android Studio cashes.

Another thing to note is that it was compiling fine the other day even with this dependency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [JOML for Android](https://github.com/JOML-CI/JOML/wiki#gradle-setup-for-android) instead of the Java version.

**Application build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
      maven {
        url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/"
      }
      ...
    }
    ...
  }
```

**App build.gradle**

```
dependencies {
    implementation "org.joml:joml-android:1.9.3-SNAPSHOT"
}
```